# $window.sessionStorage for login and logout ( token based);

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I create a login and logout function with Node.js and Angular.js which is token based. The token I am saving into window storage.

The problem is if I logout it just logout for one browser and also if I loggedin it not recognize if I am already loggedin. I think I have to extend my programm.

My question is how can I delete the storage for every open browser where I loggedin? Or schould I ask within my code if I am loggedin and how could I do this?

Thanks in advance!

**NODE.JS CODE**

```
app.post('/logout', function(req, res){

    jwt.verify(req.body.token, 'secretKey', function(err, decoded) {
        console.log("Decoded " + decoded);
        if(decoded._id != null){
        User.findOne({
        _id : decoded._id
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error occured', err);

        } else {
            if (user) {
                res.end();
            }

    }
    });
    }else{

        Console.log("Could not logout");
    }
    });

});

app.post('/login', function(req, res) {

    User.findOne({
        email : req.body.email
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error occured', err);

        } else {
            if (user) {

                // check if password matches
                if (req.body.password != undefined) {
                    var hashPWCheck = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password);
                    // true
                    //console.log(hashPWCheck);
                    if (!(hashPWCheck)) {
                        res.json({
                            success : false,
                            message : 'Authentication failed. Wrong password.'
                        });
                        console.log('Authentication failed. Wrong password.');
                    } else {
                        var token = jwt.sign(user, 'secretKey', {
                            expiresInMinutes : 60 // expires in 1 Minute
                        });

                        res.json({token : token, email : user.email});
                        console.log("Token created & sent to  Client(UserCtrlLogin): " + token);
                    }

                } else {
                    console.log("Password is required!");
                }

            } else {
                console.log("Incorect E-Mail");
            }

        }

    });
});
```

**ANGULAR.js Code**

```
app.controller('UserCtrlLogin', function($scope, $http, $window, $location, $rootScope) {

    $scope.logout = function(){
        var sessionlogout = $window.sessionStorage.getItem('token');


        var formData = {
            token : sessionlogout

        };  

    $http.post('/logout', formData).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        if(status == 200){


            $rootScope.isAlive = false;
            $rootScope.ali = false;
            $window.sessionStorage.removeItem('token');


        }else{
            $window.sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
            $rootScope.isAlive = false;
        }
        });      

    };


    $scope.signin = function() {

        var formData = {
            email : $scope.email,
            password : $scope.password
        };

        // $window.sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
        $http.post('/login', formData).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log('Data: ' + data.email);
            //console.log('Status: ' + status);
            if (status == 200) {
                if(data.email == "goekguel.ali@gmail.com"){
                    $rootScope.ali = true;

                }

                $rootScope.isAlive = true;

                $window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', data.token);
                console.log("Token saved into Storage from Server(Node.js function /login)");



            }
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
            $window.sessionStorage.removeItem('token');
        });

    };

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to save tokens in the database, and if you log in or log out in one browser you have to mark token as valid/invalid, and in another browser it's required to check token status on backend.

P.s. See [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer), it's just my recommendation for front-end auth module.